# SurveyMonkey Metadata API availability

Tags: surveymonkey

I am exploring SurveyMonkey APIs for version 3.

I would like to know is there any **Metadat API** available to get the comprehensive request-response structure for all the endpoints available for SurveyMonkey?

I could not find any such details on the documentation :
https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#getting-started

If no do you plan to support it in future.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current plan at SurveyMonkey to provide a Metadata API. What is your use case for such an API?

It may be added to the roadmap if there is enough value, but currently there is no plan.